# How to make social buttons work with location.hash

Tags: javascript, social-networking

I created some gallery script in jQuery (http://creotiv.in.ua/examples/photowall/ - slightly NSFW) and want to add social buttons to every image, so users can like each image separately.
But after adding social buttons I saw that they don't use url hash part, but I used it to navigate through all images.

If you click on a gallery image you will see three social media buttons at the bottom. They are using the gallery URL instead of each individual image's URL.

May be someone know how to make Twitter, Google+ and Facebook buttons to use page location hash, and change it if it was changed?

Here is code that generate social buttons:

```
(function(w, d, s) {
  function go(){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], load = function(url, id) {
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.src = url; js.id = id;
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    };
    load('https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1', 'fbjssdk');
    load('https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js', 'gplus1js');
    load('https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', 'tweetjs');
  }
  if (w.addEventListener) { w.addEventListener("load", go, false); }
  else if (w.attachEvent) { w.attachEvent("onload",go); }
}(window, document, 'script'));
```

Comment: Warning - tasteful site, but there are some boobies.

Comment: How are you creating your social media buttons? Code generated server side or client side? Can you post the code?

Comment: This boobies part of my work, because i'm photographer)

Comment: added social code to the description. HTML code is standard for each button.
Main problem is that i can recreate social buttons on each photo change, but it's to hard for client(so this is not an answer)

Comment: Also this buttons not working even with window.history.push(); that change all url not only hash part.

Answer (score 0):

Hash part of the URL is processed only by the web browser user interface and it is ignored by HTML parsers.

There is a specification to make hashbanged pages crawlable:

```
 https://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html
```

However no crawler or site support it yet.

You need to figure out a way to use real URLs for images instead of hashbang urls.

Comment: I use hash to navigate in jquery gallery. For example photo1 - example.com/#p=1, photo2 - example.com/#p=2
It's not for crawlers it's for users so they can save url to the full-screen image they liked. 
Also so they can share url for this image i added social buttons. But problem is that they don't use hash part of the url, or used it only once on load.

Comment: Aha. Sorry :( I was thinking that Facebook sharing (after the share clicked) screen gives you incorrect URL and photo preview, because it doesn't read the hash.

Comment: Facebook and google sharing really giving incorrect url, because when i share url with hash it remove hash from it and save only main part and search part

Answer (score 0):

Ok... let's try again. Those sharing scripts, when run during load() use the existing window.location to grab the URL and generate the  HTML. URL is stored in this HTML and this HTML is generated only once. I guess they don't expose API do dynamically update URL inside the component. You cannot access  data from the parent frame, so you cannot update URL yourself.

For Facebook, you could use Facebook Javascript SDK to have more low level access over sharing widget. I don't know whether this holds true for other social networks.

Sounds better? :)

Comment: Not really( If they build url on load - this is bug, because url can change. Many scripts and all Flash pages uses hash part to do navigation.

Comment: i think there is no normal way to do this. and this is realy bad.

Comment: Please submit your feedback to the corresponding API authors and they might be fix it in the future versions

Answer (score 0):

Found only one solution for this problem. Reinit all social buttons on url change. Like so:

```
//Facebook like
if(typeof(FB) !== 'undefined')
     FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('fblike'));

//Google plus one
if(typeof(gapi) !== 'undefined') {
    gapi.plusone.render(document.getElementById('gplus'),{
        'href':location.href,
        'annotation':'bubble',
        'width': 90,
        'align': 'left',
        'size': 'medium'
    });
}

//Twitter tweet button
if(typeof(twttr) !== 'undefined') {
    $('.twitter-share-button').attr('data-url',location.href);
    twttr.widgets.load();
}
```

with html code like this:

```
<div style="float:left;margin-top: 5px;width:80px;">
    <div id="gplus" class="g-plusone" data-size="medium"></div>
</div>
<div style="float:left;margin-top:5px;width:90px;">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
</div>
<div style="float:left;margin-top:5px;width:80px;" id="fblike">
    <fb:like send="false" layout="button_count" width="100" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
</div>
```

But there is still exist bug with G+ button, because it use correct url for sharing, but not for counting